# Change Activity contents based on options of a spinner?

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner

I am quite new to android. I want to change activity contents based on the selected option from a spinner. for example i have two options in a spinner "Option2" and "Option2" and two date pickers. I want my activity to work this way that when i select option 1 i should see one date picker and when i select option 2 i see two date pickers dynamically.

Here is my code for spinner

```
Spinner spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
final List<String> List=new ArrayList<String>();
    List.add("Option1");
    List.add("Option2");

ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,List);
    Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    triptype.setAdapter(Adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
            @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int pos1=position;
            selectedOption=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            //---save the values in the EditText view to preferences---
            editor.putInt("index", pos1);
            editor.putString("value", selectedoption);

            //---saves the values---
            editor.commit();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to create datepicker runtime then u should add two of your datepickers in your xml file.remember, keep both position of datepickers on xml is same. and set both visibility to "GONE".

class file:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
        @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //set visibility of datepicker
       if(position==0)
        {
           set "visible" to datepicker1,
           set "gone" to datepicker2.
        }
       if(position==1)
        {
           set "gone" to datepicker1,
           set "visible" to datepicker2.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the timePicker dynamically on spinners on onItemSelected method

```
   @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int pos1=position;
for(int i=0;i<mainlayout.getChildCount();i++)
{
   View v=mainlayout.getChildAt(i)
   if(v instanceof TimePicker)
    mainlayout.removeView(v);

}

if(pos==0)
{
    TimePicker t=new TimePicker (context);
    mainlayout.addView(t);
 }


else
{


TimePicker t1=new TimePicker (context);
    mainlayout.addView(t1);

TimePicker t2=new TimePicker (context);
    mainlayout.addView(t2);
}   
    }
```